# Could we please have a separate search tag for (duplicate) questions?

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, duplicate-questions, search

Questions that are marked as duplicates are now distinct from those closed for quality reasons.  However, they are both still found using `closed:1` in searches.  As a moderator I want to look at lists of each type of question separately.

If there is not already a way I am requesting a `duplicate:1` search tag for the purpose of separating these results.

Comment: To the close voters: please do not close my question.  The supposed duplicate is marked \[status-completed\] and yet the feature is not implemented and there is no solution that I am aware of. (The old work-around is broken now.)

Comment: This is a duplicate. Proper "Meta" way of action in my opinion is clearing the wrong tag from the other question (already flagged, hopefully moderator will do it soon) then bump it with edit and/or bounty.